# Setting Dynamic deeplink with query param With dynamic link in Firebase Using React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

**I want to set the dynamic deep link with query param.** For example, Suppose I've got the following information, Let's say for **user1** the URL is https://example.com/res/?appId=67abeuusbev&value=55673 this link will be dynamic. i.e. for **user2** it can be https://example.com/res/?appId=67abeuusbev&value=55674. I've set up the Firebase dynamic link. For example, say *exampletest.page.link/SYu7* . Now I want to set up the deeplink in such a way that those appId and value (https://example.com/res/?appId=67abeuusbev&value=55674) can be set dynamically as a deep link whenever this link will be clicked from a web browser and based on the respective param values I can handle the link. Is there any way to do the same in the firebase dynamic link? I'm using React Native. Thanks for the consideration in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking into modify short Firebase Dynamic Links programmatically, then it's currently not possible. The only way to update the parameters configured (i.e. deep link) in a short FDL is through the Firebase console, and only short FDLs created from the console can be edited. Short FDLs created programmatically are not displayed in the FDL dashboard.

As a workaround, you can [create long FDL manually](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually) - by appending parameters and its values. Note that deep links need to be URL-encoded if it has multiple parameters.

i.e. https://exampletest.page.link/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fres%2F%3FappId%3D67abeuusbev%26value%3D55674

You can check if the deep link will be able to carry the parameters configured in it by debugging the Dynamic Link using [preview page flowchart](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#preview_page_flowchart).